# Calling a class by a variable in python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, variables

I'm new to objects and want to know if it possible to call a class by a variable name passed through a function.

```
def check_bonus(self, class_name="game"):
    self.cls = class_name
    if len(game.played_rounds_list) == 10:
        if game.played_rounds_list[9].type == "Strike":
            print("Last round strike - 2 more balls")
            self.cls()
            if game.played_rounds_list[10].type == "Strike":
                print("1 ball remaining")
                self.cls("Bonus")

        if game.played_rounds_list[9].type == "Spare":
            print("Last round spare - 1 more ball")
            self.cls("Bonus")
```

I have tried this approach but encountered the error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

What must I do to be able to call a variable function

Comment: Instead of a string representing the class name, have you tried passing the class itself?  Looking at your code, you may actually want to pass in an object, not a class.  Or possibly a function.  What is the "call" meant to do?  Are you really wanting to pass in a class, from which you could make an object?  Or an object, with properties and methods available to you?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are objects in python. So, if, for example, your class is declared in the same file, it's a variable, and you can access it by

```
game_cls = globals()['game']
game_object = game_cls(args)
```

However, since classes are objects, it would be better, instead of passing the class name, to pass the class itself. So, change you function to

```
def check_bonus(self, cls):
    self.cls = cls
```

and call it by

```
my_object.check_bonus(Game)
```